# How to alternate around directories using subprocess

Tags: python, unix, subprocess

I want to change the current directory using subprocess.

For example:

```
import os, sys, subprocess

os.environ['a'] = '/home'
os.environ['b'] = '/'

subprocess.call('cd $a', shell=True)
subprocess.call('ls', shell=True)

subprocess.call('cd $b', shell=True)
subprocess.call('ls', shell=True)
```

I think that this should work like a command line unix

```
$ export a='/home'
$ export b='/'

$ cd $a
$ ls
$ cd $b
$ ls
```

But it doesn't happen..

How must I do to change the current dir?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. The subdirectory of the subprocess doesn't affect the directory of the current process. What do you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To change the directory just use `os.chdir()` instead.

You can also execute commands in specific directoeies by running `subprocess.Popen(...)` - it has an optional parameter `cwd=None`. Just use it to specify the working directory.

Also, you could take a look at a small module I wrote that completes some missing functionality from Python standard library. Probably this module especially https://github.com/ssbarnea/tendo/blob/master/tendo/tee.py

Comment: BTW, you cannot change the current directory of the calling process from the called project. I don't even see why would you ever want to do this.

Comment: how the post answers the question?

Comment: Well, by the way.. I think that os.chdir() will solve my trouble!! =D

Tks a lot!! I will help me so much! =D